# AngularJS override ng-model-options updateOn submit

Tags: angularjs

I have an input field which will update the corresponding model when the form is submitted using `ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'submit'}"`

However, I have occasions where I need to update the model before submission. Is there a way to override this delay and force a model to update without having to programatically submit the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[$commitViewValue()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) sorts this out:

```
$scope.myForm.myFieldName.$commitViewValue();
```

Comment: Saved the day! Thx :)